# Adding strings and variants in Delphi

Tags: delphi, variants

The way adding strings and variants behaves in Delphi (10.2 Tokyo) was a complete surprise to me. Can someone provide a reasonable explanation for this "feature" or shall we call it a bug ?

```
function unexpected: string;
var v: Variant;
begin
  result := '3';
  v := 2;
  result := v + result;
  ShowMessage(result);  //displays 5, I expected 23

  result := '3';
  v := 2;
  result := result + '-' + v;
  ShowMessage(result)   //displays -1, I expected 3-2
end;
```

Comment: Explicitly setting `VarAsType(v,varUString)` would bring your results as expected.

Comment: yes I know, or using VarToStr(), but the point was I also expected compiler to convert any variant references to string in the above expression. thanks to hnd I now know better

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### `result := v + result`

Delphi's `Variant` type is a slightly extended version of the Win32 API's `VARIANT` type and supposed to be compatible with it so long as you do not use any Delphi-specific types. Additionally, when you use Delphi-specific string types, it is supposed to behave like it would with the OLE string type. In the Win32 API, it is specifically documented that adding a string and a number will result in a (numeric) addition, not a string concatenation, that you need to have two string operands to get a string concatenation:

[`VarAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-varadd):

> ```
> Condition                                          Result
> Both expressions are strings                       Concatenated
> [...]
> One expression is numeric and the other a string   Addition
> [...]
> ```

I suspect `VarAdd` is defined like that to make things easier for VB users.

### `result := result + '-' + v`

Here `result + '-'` should perform string concatenation since both operands are strings. `'3-' + v` is then treated as a numeric addition, requiring `3-` to be parsed as a number. I believe that since there are contexts in which the sign follows the digits, this parse succeeds and produces `-3`. Adding `2` to that results in `-1`.

Comment: Ultimately it is down to the API. The matrix in "variants.SimpleVarOp" dictates that a sting ('3-') concatenated with an integer (2) should produce a double and calls "oleaut32.VarR8FromStr" for '3-' using the user default locale, which converts the string to -3.